# Is there an end to Game Dev Story?

Tags: game-dev-story

I already shipped a console, have practically infinite money, have won a lot of awards, and was not offered to move to a bigger office than the one I have (I think I moved 3 times).

The game has become quite repetitive, so I was wondering if there was something interesting in the future or if the only point is to continue to increase fans and money, or if this is *the end* of the game.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "game" ends after year 20, in terms of getting your assets in the highscore list. You can play indefinitely after this however, if you wish. The point is to make as much $ as possible the first 20 years.